# Saving tables, graphs and View() things in R

Tags: r, report

I am trying to create automatic reports in R. When i try and include matrix in the layout of a table using `grid.draw()` it doesnt show the whole table. When i use `View()` it displays the whole table in the exact way that I want it to. However I can't find a way to save this to input it straight into my document. I want to use `grid.draw()` because it creates a nice table of my data just like the `View()` function does.

this is an image of what appears when i use `View()` which is preferably what i want to save:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmKxd.png

here is what happens when i use `grid.draw()`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dix3f.png

I have tried to use things like `save()` and `png()` but I cant find a way that works

Here is my data for this matrix:

```
Nnn<-c(112702.0, 154319.2, 116803.5, 118352.5)
Fdates<-c("14Q3","14Q4","15Q1","15Q2")
FArimaWF<-c(116077.5, 154534.5, 120126.6, 121559.2)
fforcedFb<-c(109010.1, 139699.8, 108190.0, 109642.0)
mapeforced<-c(3.275821, 9.473478, 7.374378, 7.359814)
fArimaWFqb<-c(109284.0, 142633.6, 108100.8, 109646.3)
mapeout<-c(3.032732, 7.572336, 7.450796, 7.356181)
allforecasts<-matrix(c(Nnn,Fdates,fArimaWF,fforcedFb,mapeforced,fArimaWFqb,mapeout),ncol=7,byrow=FALSE)
colnames(allforecasts)<-c("Original data last 4 totals","Forecast Quarter","ARIMA forecasts on full data","ARIMA forecasts on forced parameters","MAPE of forced forecasts","ARIMA forecasts on out-sample","MAPE of out-sample forecasts")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(tableGrob(allforecasts)) # here shows how the graph is cut off in the plot viewer
View(allforecasts)
png("allallall.png")
grid.draw(tableGrob(allforecasts))
dev.off() #find the place where it saved and you can see that it saves with it cut off too
```

Comment: "automatic reports" --> use Sweave or knitr

Comment: i know how to make automatic reports. and i know about Sweave and knitr, this isnt the issue. i want to save the table, or find a way to show and save the whole table while using grid.draw

Comment: Well, explain in the question why you *must* use `grid.draw` and provide a minimal reproducible example with code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: okay done is there any other information needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
png("allallall.png")
t1<-tableGrob(allforecasts)
grid.arrange(t1)
dev.off()
```

this saves any matrix as a table in a nice format.

you can also do this for graphs:

```
png("graph1.png")
plot.ts(Nnn)
dev.off()
```